# How to align images in one row?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to align images in one row but it doesn't seem to be working. I have tried flex but the last logo is still on another row.

```
<section id="clients" class="clients clients">
<div class="container">

    <div class="row content">

        <div class="col-3">
            <img src="logo1" class="img-fluid srl" alt="">
        </div>

        <div class="col-3">
            <img src="logo2" class="img-fluid" alt="">
        </div>

        <div class="col-3">
            <img src="logo3" class="img-fluid" alt="">
        </div>

        <div class="col-3">
            <img src="logo4" class="img-fluid" alt="">
        </div>

        <div class="col-2">
            <img src="logo5" class="img-fluid" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

```
 .clients {
background: #f3f9fd;
padding: 0px 0px;
text-align: center;
}

.clients .col-lg-2 {
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
}

.clients img {
width: 70%;
-webkit-filter: grayscale(100);
filter: grayscale(100);
transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
display: inline-block;
padding: 10px 0;
}

.clients img:hover {
-webkit-filter: none;
filter: none;
transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

[image: Move the last logo to the same row as others]

As you can see the last logo is in its own row but I want it to be on the same row as the rest of them but i cant seem to do this?

Thanks

Comment: the total is bigger than 12 so either make the total of the col-* equal to 12 or simply uise col without numbers

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? It should not be too hard to check this problem through your browser's developer tools

Answer (score 1):

Your idea was flawed in using `col-3`
bootstrap grid system is divided into 12 spaces
`col-1` uses 1 space
`col-2` uses 2 spaces
an so on

Your images all have `col-3` and there is 5 of them which is taking 15 "spaces" which is more than 12 thats why last element is moved down.

When you check [bootstrap documentation for grid system](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/grid/) you will find that you don't have to speciy how many spaces col needs to take.

You can use `.col` which will take as many width as it need for all elements to fill whole parent element

```css
.clients {
    background: #f3f9fd;
    padding: 0px 0px;
    text-align: center;
}

.clients .col {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.clients img {
    width: 70%;
    /* just for presentation*/ min-height: 50px;
    /* just for presentation*/ background-color: red;
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100);
    filter: grayscale(100);
    transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 0;
}

.clients img:hover {
    -webkit-filter: none;
    filter: none;
    transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

```html
<!-- CSS only -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">

<section id="clients" class="clients clients">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row content">
            <div class="col">
                <img src="logo1" class="img-fluid srl" alt="">
            </div>

            <div class="col">
                <img src="logo2" class="img-fluid" alt="">
            </div>

            <div class="col">
                <img src="logo3" class="img-fluid" alt="">
            </div>

            <div class="col">
                <img src="logo4" class="img-fluid" alt="">
            </div>

            <div class="col">
                <img src="logo5" class="img-fluid" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```